# How to flash different patterns of LED with Flip Flops

Tags: flipflop

I need to blink  same LED's in different patterns using flip flops. I have figured out the logic of individual patterns but I don't see a way to map them with inputs in order to differentiate the patterns.

For instance,suppose I have 4 LED's and I want to blink them in  4 different patterns. Say  even, odd, Fibonacci sequence, Prime numbers given that I have already implemented each of them individually. How can I design my circuit such that the same LED's blink:

1) In the sequence of even numbers if I input (00)
2) Odd numbers if I input (01)
3) Fibonacci if I input (10)
4) Prime numbers if I input (11)

Comment: Do you want to input a binary into your circuit, using push buttons, and then continusly represent all the bits, using flipflops to hold the last inputed value?

Answer (score 2):

It's not clear what you really want to do, or how flip flops are supposed achieve it, but a microcontroller is the obvious solution.  Drive the LEDs from four different outputs of the micro, and the rest is firmware.  Trying to derive things like Fibonacci series and prime numbers using flip flops is just plain silly.

Comment: The Flip flops's output(Q) would be connected to an LED. IF I have 4 such LED's connected. If all of them blink at the same time. It would represent 15